# plsql advanced or condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, or-operator

I have a table containing post adresses.
my query looks like this:

```
SELECT "ID", postcode, numbertype, minnumber, maxnumber
INTO huidigPostcodeID_FK, databasePostcode, databaseNumberType, databaseMinNumber, databaseMaxNumber
FROM POSTCODE 
WHERE POSTCODE_ID = 79417568 AND (NUMBERTYPE = 'odd' OR NUMBERTYPE = 'mixed')
```

In most cases this works fine since it has to deliver 1 row only.
in the case when there are 2 identical recors (one with numbertype = odd and the other mixed)
the query returns 2 rows.

```
        ID POSTCODE NUMBERTYPE  MINNUMBER  MAXNUMBER
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    395755 7941KD   odd                 9          9 
    395756 7941KD   mixed               1         22
```

I don't want this because I get an error by this. Has somebody a solution wherein the programm only gets one record with numbertype = 'mixed' in it?

So in the above example I only wan't this record to show up:

```
    ID POSTCODE NUMBERTYPE  MINNUMBER  MAXNUMBER
```

---

```
395756 7941KD   mixed               1         22
```

Comment: select into woudln't maken any sense if it wasn't plsql, but your right

Comment: Edit your question and show the record that you want to get.

Comment: So what's the wanted result?

Comment: It's still an `OR` condition for the SQL part. It's not a PL/SQL question.

Comment: Ok, so I worked around it. Since only record didn't even have enough information for me to check. So I made a nested block with the same statement, one searching for mixed the other for odd (or even, it's a variable in code). Made an exception handler for no_data_found in the first block, in the handler the search for odd or even starts. Fixed it this way it seems.

Comment: By the way, you can avoid the parentheses around the `OR` condition by using the `IN` operator instead: `AND numbertype IN ('odd','mixed')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one might also use a window function to accomplish this:

```
SELECT "ID", postcode, numbertype, minnumber, maxnumber
  INTO huidigPostcodeID_FK, databasePostcode, databaseNumberType, databaseMinNumber, databaseMaxNumber
  FROM (
    SELECT "ID", postcode, numbertype, minnumber, maxnumber
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY postcode ORDER BY DECODE(numbertype, 'mixed', 0, 1) ) AS rn
      FROM postcode
     WHERE postcode_id = 79417568 AND (numbertype = 'odd' OR numbertype = 'mixed')
) WHERE rn = 1
```

In this case, if there are two records for a given value of `postcode`, it will select the one where the value of `numbertype` is `'mixed'`. One might also simply use `ORDER BY numbertype` in the `OVER( )` clause but that's not as explicit in saying that `'mixed'` ought to come first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation.  But it is unclear exactly what you want.  Something like:

```
SELECT min(id), postcode,
       (case when min(numbertype) = max(numbertype) then min(numbertype)
             else 'mixed'
        end)
       min(minnumber), max(maxnumber)
INTO huidigPostcodeID_FK, databasePostcode, databaseNumberType, databaseMinNumber, databaseMaxNumber
FROM POSTCODE 
WHERE POSTCODE_ID = 79417568 AND (NUMBERTYPE = 'odd' OR NUMBERTYPE = 'mixed')
GROUP BY postcode
```